# What is wrong with this Batch file

Tags: batch, redirection, dir

```
 e:
 cd \My Files
 dir a:\ >\Prt2Txt\adrv1.txt\
 pause
```

results in:

```
 E:\My Files>nhm
 E:\My Files>e:
 E:\My Files>cd \My Files
 E:\My Files>dir a:\  1>\Prt2Txt\adrv1.txt\
 The system cannot find the path specified.
 E:\My Files>pause
 Press any key to continue . . .
```

1. Where did the extra spaces come from?
2. Where did the "1" come from?

I tried it with the full pathname `"E:\My Files\..."` ,
but the "My " seemed to be the problem.

Comment: `cd "\My Files"`

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is you are trying to write the output of the dir command to a directory:

```
dir a:\ >\Prt2Txt\adrv1.txt\
```

should be

```
dir a:\ >\Prt2Txt\adrv1.txt
```

(No trailing slash.)

Answer (score 0):

Not unlike Unix, Windows allows different I/O streams
to be redirected places, so you can do

```
command args > fileA 2> fileB
```

to send standard output to *`fileA`* and standard error to *`fileB`*. 
Standard output is file descriptor 1, so `>` is equivalent to `1>`. 
For some reason, when you run a batch file with `ECHO ON`,
CMD displays `>` as  `1>`. 
I guess this is meant to make things less ambiguous;
as your question demonstrates,
it seems to create more confusion than clarity.

`The system cannot find the path specified.` can mean
either that `A:` or `E:\Prt2Txt` does not exist. 
Try `dir a:\` (without output redirection)
and try `e:` followed by `echo test >\Prt2Txt\adrv1.txt\`;
you’ll probably see that one (or both) of them fail.